# How to label matching items in a nested list in Python

Tags: python, list, loops, nested

Slightly new to Python here.

I currently have a list of nested lists. I am trying to label each sublist starting from 0-25. 
However, if two sublists are the same, they should have the same label.

For example:

```
label_list = [['AH0'], ['AA1', 'K', 'S'], ['AH0', 'N', 'T'], ['AA1', 'K', 'S'], ['IH0', 'N'], ['AA1', 'K', 'S']]
```

The output should be `[0, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1]`

since the second, fourth, and sixth sublists are the same. The rest of the sublists should just be labelled in consecutive numeric order.
I know i need to use a loop but I am quite stuck, anyone have any advice on how to approach this?
Thank you.

Comment: Is it intentional that your output has a 4 but not a 3?

Comment: @Kevin I think the essence of the problem is that if an element in `label_list` has not yet been iterated over, then its label is its current index in the list. If the element has been seen, then its label is the index of the first occurrence of the same element.

Comment: @Ajax1234, that's a sensible interpretation of the expected output. My original interpretation is that if an element has not been iterated over, then its label is the smallest number that hasn't been emitted yet. I think this makes more sense in relation to "consecutive numeric order", but of course only if the 4 really is a typo.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a dictionary:

```
label_list = [['AH0'], ['AA1', 'K', 'S'], ['AH0', 'N', 'T'], ['AA1', 'K', 'S'], ['IH0', 'N'], ['AA1', 'K', 'S']] 
count = 0
d = {}
for i in label_list:
  if tuple(i) not in d:
    d[tuple(i)] = count
  count += 1

final_result = [d[tuple(i)] for i in label_list]
```

Output:

```
[0, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1]
```

Edit: the solution above assumes that labels are generated based on the index of the first occurrence of a unique value. However, if a general incrementation is needed, and the labels are to be created based-on the number of unique elements seen, then `count` can be moved inside the for-loop:

```
if tuple(i) not in d:
  d[tuple(i)] = count
  count += 1
```

Then, the output is `[0, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1]`.

A list comprehension can also be used, although it is not as efficient:

```
c = iter(range(len(label_list)))
new_d = {tuple(a):i for i, a in reversed(list(enumerate(label_list)))}
final_result = [next(c) if a not in label_list[:i] else new_d[tuple(a)] for i, a in enumerate(label_list)]
```

Output:

```
[0, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a one-liner, just for fun:

```
 [dict( map( reversed, enumerate( set( map(tuple, label_list)))))[tuple(item)] for item in label_list]
```

The downside (besides being unreadable) is that it creates the dictionary as many times as items you have in your label_list.

To explain how it works, read it from the inside out:

`map(tuple, label_list)` applies (or 'maps') the tuple function to each element of label_list, so that each element can serve as a key in the dictionary later (python lists cannot be dictionary keys)

`set( map(tuple, label_list))` creates a set of all unique elements in label_list, which we need since you want a unique label for each unique entry

`enumerate( set( map(tuple, label_list)))` enumerate is a function that takes some list as input and returns a unique (in order) integer for each element of the list. So what you get is a list of tuples like this [(0,element_0), (1, element_1) ...]

`map( reversed, enumerate( set( map(tuple, label_list))))` this reverses the elements of the above list, so that when we create the dictionary in the next step, the elements will be the keys rather than the integers. So we get [(element_0, 0), (element_1, 0) ...]

`dict( map( reversed, enumerate( set( map(tuple, label_list)))))` simply takes the list of tuples we had from the last step and creates a dictionary from it, they keys of which we can access just like any other dictionary (i.e. with `dictionary[element]` syntax.)

The rest of the line is just like any other list comprehension. It iterates over your original label_list and accesses the dictionary we created to get the unique number associated with each element.